# Extracting values as a dictionary from dataframe based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with unique value in each columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Phys","Shane","NY"],["Chem","Mark","LA"],
                    ["Maths","Jack","Mum"],["Bio","Sam","CT"]],
                    columns = ["cls1","cls2","cls3"])
print(df1)

    cls1    cls2    cls3
0   Phys    Shane   NY
1   Chem    Mark    LA
2   Maths   Jack    Mum
3   Bio     Sam     CT
```

And a list l1:

```
l1=["Maths","Bio","Shane","Mark"]
print(l1)

['Maths', 'Bio', 'Shane', 'Mark']
```

Now I want to retrieve a columns from dataframe that contains elements from list and list of elements.

**Expected Output**:

```
{'cls1' : ['Maths','Bio'], 'cls2': ['Shane','Mark']}
```

**The code I have**:

```
cls = []
for cols in df1.columns:
    mask = df1[cols].isin(l1)
    if mask.any():
        cls.append(cols)
print(cls)
```

**The output of above code**:

```
['cls1', 'cls2']
```

I'm struggling to get common elements from dataframe and list to convert it into dictionary.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for mask, replace non match values by indexing and reshape with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df1[df1.isin(l1)].stack()
print (df)
0  cls2    Shane
1  cls2     Mark
2  cls1    Maths
3  cls1      Bio
dtype: object
```

Last create list by `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {k:v.tolist() for k,v in df.groupby(level=1)}
print(d)
{'cls2': ['Shane', 'Mark'], 'cls1': ['Maths', 'Bio']}
```

Another solution:

```
d = {}
for cols in df1.columns:
    mask = df1[cols].isin(l1)
    if mask.any():
        d[cols] = df1.loc[mask, cols].tolist()

print(d)
{'cls2': ['Shane', 'Mark'], 'cls1': ['Maths', 'Bio']}
```

Comment: The output I'm getting is `{'cls1': ['Maths', 'Bio'], 'cls2': ['Shane']}`.  It's omitting *Mark*

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - what return `df` ?

Comment: It was typo from my side. Your solution works as a charm. Thank you